# Android: Custom composite class extending LinearLayout thinks it's a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I am creating a custom composite layout that consists of a clickable horizontal LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and two TextViews.  Ultimately I want to be able to reference the entire thing using a single field and add, subtract, and edit these to my activity depending on user activity.  I'm using an XML resource that I am inflating in the constructor.  However my phone thinks I'm creating a LinearLayout and I get the following error when i try to implement the custom class:

```
D/ConnectionButton﹕ Ready to inflate
D/ConnectionButton﹕ constructor 2
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417be898)
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampleapp.app/com.exampleapp.app.ManageFriends}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.exampleapp.utils.ConnectionButton
```

The error when I am setting NameText. If I leave that line out it runs but my later Log tells me android thinks it is LinearLayout, not ConnectionButton

So here's my definition class **ConnectionButton:**

```
public class ConnectionButton extends LinearLayout {
    ImageView IconView;
    TextView  NameView;
    TextView  StatusView;

    public ConnectionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("ConnectionButton","Ready to inflate");
        addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_row, null));
        Log.d("ConnectionButton","Inflated");
        IconView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        NameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        StatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    }

    public ConnectionButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d("ConnectionButton","constructor 2");
/*        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("ConnectionButton","Ready to inflate");
        addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_row, null));
        Log.d("ConnectionButton","Inflated");*/
        IconView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        NameView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.name);
        StatusView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status);
        NameView.setText("From Constructor 2");
    }
}
```

Here's my XML resource:

```
<com.exampleapp.utils.ConnectionButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/status"/>
</com.exampleapp.utils.ConnectionButton>
```

And here is where I create it: (N.B. ConnectionList is the existing vertical LinearLayout that should contain these objects)

```
    LinearLayout box = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ConnectionList);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Log.d("ConnectionButton","Ready to inflate");
    View CBv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_row, box);
    Log.d("CBv class",CBv.getClass().toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the incorrect assumption that inflater.inflate returns the new view. According to the documentation it returns:

> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is
>   the root View; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

So in your case CBv is a LinearLayout because that's what the parent is. To get access to your view, just use findViewById.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to BladeCoder, that recursion isn't being called. The real question why does Android recognize it as a LinearLayout instead of my custom class?

Comment: OH, I think I see what's happening. You're trying to access a child in the constructor of the layout, but it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Ok, now that that's cleared up, I posted the actual answer you were looking for :-P

Comment: That's it! I thought inflate returned the element and I was tearing my hair out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're trying to inflate a `ConnectionButton` inside the constructor of `ConnectionButton` which poses a recursive problem.

I suggest that you change ConnectionButton to make it inherit from `FrameLayout` instead (since you only have one root child) and change the root type of its XML layout content to `LinearLayout`. Your control will then be an extended `FrameLayout` which contains a single `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Oh, I left that in on the first constructor, you're right. But it's commented out on the second, which is the one that's being called by the inflater.  If ConnectionButton extends FrameLayout and I had several instances of it, would there then be multiple FrameLayouts each choosing one LinearLayout and in that 3 other views?

Comment: I thought you were using the control in the opposite way: creating it by code and having it inflating its own layout.
If you let the inflater inflate your control, the problem is that the child views are added after the constructor is called so they are not yet available in the constructor and you'll get a NullPointerException while trying to set the text on "NameView". Reference the child views later, like in onFinishInflate() for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm open to either way. In the past I've created simpler custom classes programmatically. This is the first time I've used the XML inflater and I still haven't wrapped my head around it completely.  I haven't yet found documentation that gives a complete example, just bits and pieces for specific situations. (like this one :) )